# find the value of a variable in continuity function

Tags: limits, continuity

Function
$$G(x) = x-\frac{3}{\sqrt{5x+1}} - \sqrt{3x+7}$$

For what value of the constant k is the function continuous on its domain

f(x)( f(x) combine 2 function/equation together)

=g(x)      Domain:  xE Dg

=k    Domain : x = 3

I think k = 4 because when I look at the graph at desmo, g(x) have a hole at (3,4) (i have no reason why) so it is a removable discontinuity, but this  question ask me what is value of k to make f(x) a continuity function and we know that k is only available at x = 3(basically just a dot) and there is a hole at (3,4) in g(x) function so I know that k is going to be 4 to fill up the hole to make continuity.

But how do you calculate k values algebrically?

Comment: Where does $k$ appear in the formula?

Comment: why sould be a hole at $$x=3$$?

Comment: or do you mean $$G(x)=x-\frac{3}{\sqrt{5x+1}-\sqrt{3x+7}}$$?

Comment: multiply the numerator and denominator by $$\sqrt{5x+1}+\sqrt{3x+7}$$

Comment: When u go to desmo and enter the equation there is a hole at 3

Comment: there is no hole it is a pole

Comment: if you go to desmo graphing calculator, you realize that the graph look like f(x) = sqrt(x)